# chat messenger UITableViewCell, loading message

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

i am trying to load messages into my messenger using firebase, however, it isnt showing. I set my cells background to light gray and i can see it's working as the number of messages in database and cells in light gray matched.

the code i used is

```
func loadMsg() {
    let toId = user!.id!
    let fromId = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
    let ref = Database.database().reference().child("privateMessages").child(fromId).child(toId)
    ref.observe(.value) { (snapshot) in

        if let snapshot = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] {

            self.messages.removeAll()

            for data in snapshot {

                let newMsg = Message(dictionary: data.value as! [String: AnyObject])

                self.messages.append(newMsg)

            }
        }

        DispatchQueue.main.async {self.tableView.reloadData()}
    }
}
```

my firebase database looks like:
[image]

and my simulator looks like

[image]

as of my storyboard:

[image]

any reason why my text aren't showing???

***UPDATED BELOW**

i tried to configure my cells, and now it seems to be going to the right direction but I am having crash on my sentView where it crashes due to

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an
>   Optional value

my code for my tableview cell is

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase

class ChatMessageCell: UITableViewCell {

var message: Message!

@IBOutlet weak var receivedMsgLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var sentMsgLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var sentView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var receivedView: UIView!

var currentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

func configCell(message: Message) {

    self.message = message

    if message.fromId == currentUser {

        sentView.isHidden = false

        sentMsgLabel.text = message.textMessages

        receivedMsgLabel.text = ""

        receivedMsgLabel.isHidden = true

    } else {

        sentView.isHidden = true

        sentMsgLabel.text = ""

        receivedMsgLabel.text = message.textMessages

        receivedMsgLabel.isHidden = false
    }
  }

}

as for my table is 

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell: ChatMessageCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! ChatMessageCell

        let message = messages[indexPath.row]

        cell.configCell(message: message)
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray

        return cell
    }
```

am i going in the right direction?? sorry not sure where to post my codes, therefore posting it in answer section.

Comment: add your TableView code.

Comment: have added in my Tableview code

Comment: do 1 thing, put exceptional break point and test where app crash

Comment: at the moment,it is crashing at line 41, sentView.isHidden = false,
it wrote Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: did you check sentView outlet is properly connected?

Comment: yes,it is connected

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170204/discussion-between-kuldeep-and-william-loke).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "The unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions"

Crash occurs when you try and display a content before the cell is finished displaying.

Try by creating new custom cell xib and try.

register like this.

```
self.tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "TableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "TableViewCell")


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell:TableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TableViewCell") as! TableViewCell

    let message = messages[indexPath.row]

    cell.configCell(message: message)
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray

    return cell
}
```

Comment: great answer! lifesaver!